# SET row selected

Tags: java, jtable, selection, rows, setting

Im trying to SET a row selected from a JTable, I get and compare all the data received from my DB, and then when comparing if the data exists, it must set that row selected.

I've tried several functions such as setSelectionModel or setSelectionInterval and none of these are setting selected the row that has the value it must select.

Any suggestions?

heres some code....not sure it will help though...but its what I read online...not selecting the row I want at all...leerTripulantesVuelo brings back an array of Tripulante which is what I go through to select THAT Tripulante on the list.

```
ModeloTablaTripulantes tablaPil = new ModeloTablaTripulantes();
tablaPilotos.setModel(tablaPil);
tablaPilotos.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

ArrayList<Tripulante> trip = new ArrayList();

    String tipoPersona = "t";
    String numVuelo = numeroVueloListaTripulantes.getText();

    try {
        trip = Aerolinea.leerTripulantesVuelo(numVuelo);
        for (Tripulante t: trip){
            for(int i =0; i<tablaPil.getRowCount();i++){
                if (tablaPil.getValueAt(i, 0).equals(t.getCedula())){
                    tablaPilotos.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(i, i);
                }
            }

        }
    } catch (BDException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: do you have any code we can talk about?

Comment: just added some...but not sure it helps as I am looking for something which i found no comments online, haha....is there any command to setSelectedRow ? as there is for a radioButton for example

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example that selects the second line in the table.
I use NetBeans so just don't care about the code for the ui. The code in `jButton1ActionPerformed` contains `jTable1.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(row, row)` which does exactly what i expected - selecting the line.
Are you sure that your program runs to `setSelectionInterval()`? Maybe the string contains whitespaces at the end. Debugging should help to find out.

```
package tripulante;

public class Tripulante extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Tripulante() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {"sample 1", "a"},
                {"sample 2", "b"},
                {"sample 3", "c"},
                {"sample 4", "d"}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1", "Title 2"
            }
        ));
        jTable1.setAutoResizeMode(javax.swing.JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

        jButton1.setText("Select lines");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 557, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton1)
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 351, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        for (int row = 0; row < jTable1.getRowCount(); row++) {
            String cellContent=jTable1.getValueAt(row, 0).toString();
            if (cellContent.equalsIgnoreCase("sample 2")) {
                jTable1.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(row, row);
            }
        }
    }                                        

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Tripulante().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```